# Import/export manipulate state in file

Tags: manipulate

Is it possible to export the state of Manipulate with big number of parameters in file and then restore the parameters of Manipulate from this file?

Comment: Have you seen the "Take snapshot" menu item of `Manipulate`?

Comment: Yes, but it is not what I need

Comment: Does it need to work within FreePlayer?

Comment: Also, what is wrong with bookmarks and what can't be done with them but can with a file?

Comment: There is not enough data to answer the question.  Can you put up an example of Manipulate and its data, so we can see what the problem is?